# Onclick in Textview gets crashed

Tags: android

I have a `TextView` which contains `onclick` in xml.The onclick works sometimes and sometimes the app crashes.I renamed the `TextView` in xml to `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView`,but it didn't solved the issue.I found similar questions but none of solved mine.

**code**

```
 public void customerDetails(View view){
    Intent intent=new Intent(Customers.this,CustomerDetails.class);
    intent.putExtra(Common.CUSTOMERID,view.getTag().toString());
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

**My XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        app:cardElevation="1dp"
        app:cardMaxElevation="0dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/customer_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/call_button"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/amount"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/call_button"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/amount"
            android:onClick="customerDetails"
            android:text="Customer Name"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/customer_name"
            android:text="ContactPersonName"
            android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:id="@+id/contact_person_name"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/amount"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/amount"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/call_button"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/call_button"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Error is**

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method customerDetails(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView with id 'customer_name'

Comment: Did you try to setOnClickListener or do you have to use like this ?

Comment: Post full xml and your activity's inCreate()

Comment: it is the problem with android, you should try handling onClick Listener using id's.

Comment: @mTak bro my java code is much bigger

Comment: In the xml does is this line `android:onClick="customerDetails"` underlined red?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use your own class in xml,  as standrt TextView classes do not contain your custom method

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding this line to the root tag of the xml:

```
tools:context="<yourpackaggename.activityname>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add your listeners in your Activity `onCreate` method. By using lambdas, it won't grow your code more than a line for every listener:

```
findViewById(R.id.textView).setOnClickListener(v -> customerDetails(v));
```

And you can change `customerDetails` method visibility to `private` now.

This is a better practice, and you will have a better control on your listeners if you need anything more complex.